# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CricketTest2.Models.NewsDetail',

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view in Model `NewsDetail`, i have just foreach all the data on `News Index View` and want to get details by clicking on it. but whenever i'm clicking on it, i'm getting this error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CricketTest2.Models.NewsDetail', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[CricketTest2.Models.NewsDetail]'.`. I have tried enough to solve it. Please help me to sort out his problem. Thank you
Here are my code snippets.

[News Controller + NewsDetail Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRVQe.png)

[News Index and News Details View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJnk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From controller you are sending single entity of `NewsDetail` but in view you are receiving it with `IEnumerable` of `NewsDetail`. add `@model CricketTest2.Models.NewsDetail` in details page instead of `@model IEnumerable <CricketTest2.Models.NewsDetail>`

Comment: let me try it @Mahbubur

Comment: it gives error...
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: Solved Brother by removing foreach loop